# Type '"standard"' is not assignable to type 'MatFormFieldAppearance'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Updated my angular project to 15 and I notice matformfield appearance ="standard" is no longer useable.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the deprecated versions of these modules would somehow pull the angular 14 versions. so it makes appearance ="standard" useable. Seem google angular team has not found a way to make use of appearance ="standard" in angular 15.0.2 as yet[image]

Answer (score 1):

The options are now:

```
type MatFormFieldAppearance = 'fill' | 'outline';
```

see: [here](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormFieldAppearance)

You can check the differences - [here](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/angular-material-form-field-appearance/)